# Javascript scripts not loading when navigating directly to page in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, loading

http://fwy.pagodabox.com

On this home page, you can click over "friends with you" in the main nav, click, and an interactive canvas animation comes up. However, if you go to another page in the site, then click the "F" inside the circle to go home, the script does not load and the animation does not fire on click.

I think this happens because chrome handles cacheing a little differently than firefox.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of bug or know what might be causing it?

The function that fires the animation is inside of a `$j(window).load(function(){ ...` if that is any kind of hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe helps jQuerys `.on()`-function? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: When I do that I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null `

Comment: FYI, I have the same problem on FireFox V.14

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the asynchronous loading I was using. Putting the function inside a

`$(document).ready(function(){...`

Solved it